# how to call image in url management

Tags: php, twitter-bootstrap, yii

I have problem to call image with link.

i implementing url management in Yii. it working fine. but. when call image from database. image and link ie if i hover on the image. pages gets render. so dont want to render or refresh the page. i added the code following please where i did mistake. please suggest me how to call the image only

```
<?php   $image = '<img class="img-responsive" src="'.Yii::app()->baseUrl.'/img/'.$small_recipe.'" />';

            echo CHtml::link($image, array('name'=>$reciep_name,));  ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this way

```
$imghtml=CHtml::image('gallery/'.$data->gallery'.jpg', $data->picturenumber.'.jpg');
echo CHtml::link($imghtml, array('view', 'id'=>$data->id));
```